# How to exclude results from fzf.vim search

Tags: vim, fzf, vim-fzf

I use fzf.vim a lot in my work, though don't know how to exclude incorrect lines from search results. Here is an example of the problem I have.

I need to find every `model.search_views` occurrence, but get also `model.search_views_smth` occurrence also. How to exclude the last one from results?

It seems to be obvious, but I spent a lot of time and didn't find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the [Search syntax](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#search-syntax) section in the official `fzf` docs to be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing.